Use a .properties file to pass configuration variables to Logstash
I am setting Logstash on Docker, and the deployment chart gets some environment variables and places them in a file secrets.properties inside the container,
What I want to do is use this file to pass those variables into Logstash and use them as environnement variables (for example for the password of jdbc_input),
Is there any workaround to do so, for example pass this file to jvm and read those settings?

You could replace your dockerfile's entry point with a shell script that reads your secret file then creates the expected env vars before executing the original endpoint. Then your logstash config can use the ${varname} syntax to pull in the values dynamically, and your secret env vars are only available to child processes of your entrypoint script - nice and tidy. But as this isnt a programming question i am going to vote to close as off topic though - you will get a better answer over on superuser.com/serverfault.com. Good luck!

Thank you MisterSmith for the answer, I didn't know that there is another forum for ops, so when you say creates the env vars you meant as system vars, so there no other way to pass those vars as file?
